# Configuring GridFS template in spring-data for MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

i'm having troubles configuring MongoDB in my spring application (I use Spring Data for mongo db). Here is the part of configuration that responsible for mongodb

```
<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017"/>
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="yourdb" />

<mongo:mapping-converter id="converter" />

<bean name="gridFsTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg ref="converter" />
</bean>
```

When i start application i get the following log:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'converter': Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:278)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]   ... 93 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:164)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:125)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:270)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]   ... 102 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper.(DefaultMongoTypeMapper.java:49)
>   ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.(MappingMongoConverter.java:110)
>   ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.(MappingMongoConverter.java:126)
>   ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_05]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_05]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_05]    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_05]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]   ... 104 common frames
>   omitted

I assume that i should add 'type-mapper-ref' to the 'converted' bean but i have no idea what value should i provide.

This example has almost similar configuration: http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-save-binary-file-gridfs-example/

Maybe some of you who are more familiar with mongodb can give me an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed version of spring-data-mongodb from '1.5.0.RC' to '1.5.0.RELEASE' and version of spring-data-commons from '1.8.0.RC1' to '1.8.0.RELEASE' and it fixed the problem. Probably api was changed and 'NoSuchMethodError' no longer appears.